# Looping a local mp4 file with Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, mp4

I'm trying to set up a display for work, and have an mp4 file saved to my C:\ drive that I would like to play on loop.

The only mp4 player that I can install however is Google Chrome Browser, and there doesn't seem to be a simple way to loop the video.

Can anyone suggest a simple way I might be able to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Seeing that you added the `html` tag, you can [solve it like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8088660/1057527).

Comment: @machineaddict - I can't get the video to even play using those links

Comment: Alternatively, if you can install Chrome, you can install Firefox. Load the mp4 file, right click, then choose Loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this natively in Chrome.

I dragged the MP4 from my desktop to Chrome then rightclicked on it in the browser and selected "Loop".

[image: A screenshot of an MP4 video looping in Chrome]

Answer (score 0):

This extension worked for me https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/loop/mpjplegmigckokmkmnbbfgjpepocpngj

Checked several Chrome Extensions, to loop video in notion (don't see loop option by default), this was the first which worked correctly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).